# How to delete instance of persistent object when last client has finished

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, object-persistence

I'm trying to implement an object persistence model in C++. The idea is that there is a Database object that acts as a factory for various PersistentObjects, each of which being associated with a row in a database table. The Database has a method like this:

```
PersistentObject *Database::GetObject(int ID);
```

This returns a pointer to an object with the ID number supplied (or a null pointer if the ID doesn't exist). In the Database class, there is also a map of all PersistentObjects that have been created:

```
std::map<int, PersistentObject*> _objectMap;
```

Internally, GetObject does one of two things:

1. If this is the first time the PersistentObject with the ID has been requested then it queries the database, constructs a new instance of PersistentObject based on the result, inserts that object address into the map(with the ID as the key) and returns a pointer to the new object.
2. If the PersistentObject has previously been loaded (i.e. the ID already exists as a key in the map), it just returns a pointer to that object.

The reason for keeping track of the PersistentObjects centrally is that I have another thread that continually polls the database for changes to loaded PersistentObjects and sends an event to any object that is out of date.

What I want to be able to do is garbage-collect the central object map in Database so that when there are no remaining references to a particular object in the client code, the object is removed from the map and deleted, and is no longer checked by the update monitoring thread.

I thought of doing this with shared_ptr, but the problem is if that I use a shared_ptr in the map, then the reference count never gets to zero even when the object is no longer in use. I can't keep a traditional pointer to the PersistentObject in the map and create multiple shared_ptrs from it.

Does anybody know of a way to do this? I almost need a shared_ptr that will call the deleter when the reference count gets to 1 rather than 0. Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _"if that I use a shared_ptr in the map, then the reference count never gets to zero "_ Would `weak_ptr` solve your problems?

Comment: Your requirements are specific, a generic solution won't get you all the the way there, but you can use standard parts though. A returned `shared_ptr`, a `weak_ptr` in the map and a custom deleter with the first created `shared_ptr` that will both notify your "change watcher" thread and delete the `PersistentObject*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way should be to return a `shared_ptr` to the Client but to store a `weak_ptr` in your map. `weak_ptr` do not increment the reference count and can easily produce more `shared_ptr` using `lock()`. You will have to watch your objects for expiration though, except you implement a custom deleter that cleans up the "dead" reference.

Comment: To get the "last client" event he is looking for (for the "change watching" thread), a custom deleter for the `shared_ptr` should also be included.

Comment: Or, the change watching thread could be responsible for pruning the map.  When it goes and examines the map, remove any weak_ptrs that are no longer pointing to a valid object.

Comment: But you would have to check in your watcher thread and your GetObject Methode. So a custom deleter seems to be the nicest way.

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree - weak pointer in the map and a custom deleter is how I'm going to implement this.